# Slim 4 - Registering and Accessing Routes

Tags: php, routes, slim-4

I have just created slim 4 project using "composer create-project slim\slim-skeleton appdb". I have a routes.php as

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use App\Application\Actions\User\ListUsersAction;
use App\Application\Actions\User\ViewUserAction;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;
use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use Slim\App;
use Slim\Interfaces\RouteCollectorProxyInterface as Group;

return function (App $app) {

    $app->post('/hello', function (Request $request, Response $response) {
        $response->getBody()->write('Hello world!');
        return $response;
    });

};
```

and the index.php as

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

use App\Application\Handlers\HttpErrorHandler;
use App\Application\Handlers\ShutdownHandler;
use App\Application\ResponseEmitter\ResponseEmitter;
use DI\ContainerBuilder;
use Slim\Factory\AppFactory;
use Slim\Factory\ServerRequestCreatorFactory;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

// Instantiate PHP-DI ContainerBuilder
$containerBuilder = new ContainerBuilder();

if (false) { // Should be set to true in production
    $containerBuilder->enableCompilation(__DIR__ . '/../var/cache');
}

// Set up settings
$settings = require __DIR__ . '/../app/settings.php';
$settings($containerBuilder);

// Set up dependencies
$dependencies = require __DIR__ . '/../app/dependencies.php';
$dependencies($containerBuilder);

// Set up repositories
$repositories = require __DIR__ . '/../app/repositories.php';
$repositories($containerBuilder);

// Build PHP-DI Container instance
$container = $containerBuilder->build();

// Instantiate the app
AppFactory::setContainer($container);
$app = AppFactory::create();
$callableResolver = $app->getCallableResolver();

// Register middleware
$middleware = require __DIR__ . '/../app/middleware.php';
$middleware($app);

// Register routes
$routes = require __DIR__ . '/../app/routes.php';
$routes($app);

/** @var bool $displayErrorDetails */
$displayErrorDetails = $container->get('settings')['displayErrorDetails'];

// Create Request object from globals
$serverRequestCreator = ServerRequestCreatorFactory::create();
$request = $serverRequestCreator->createServerRequestFromGlobals();

// Create Error Handler
$responseFactory = $app->getResponseFactory();
$errorHandler = new HttpErrorHandler($callableResolver, $responseFactory);

// Create Shutdown Handler
$shutdownHandler = new ShutdownHandler($request, $errorHandler, $displayErrorDetails);
register_shutdown_function($shutdownHandler);

// Add Routing Middleware
$app->addRoutingMiddleware();

// Add Error Middleware
$errorMiddleware = $app->addErrorMiddleware($displayErrorDetails, false, false);
$errorMiddleware->setDefaultErrorHandler($errorHandler);

// Run App & Emit Response
$response = $app->handle($request);
$responseEmitter = new ResponseEmitter();
$responseEmitter->emit($response);
```

Attempts to access post route as 127.0.0.1/appdb/public/hello/Peter, gives an error

{ "statusCode": 404, "error": { "type": "RESOURCE_NOT_FOUND", "description": "Not found." } }

What am I doing wrong?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried `127.0.0.1/appdb/public/hello`?

Comment: It seems you are able to serve the app on poprt 80 correctly. Try visitinc `localhost/hello`. The only defined route in your app is `/hello`, so any other address including `/appdb/public/hello` should return a 404 error.

Comment: Yes, I have tried 127.0.0.1/appdb/public/hello. It still gives a 404 error

Comment: @NigelRen, I also tried localhost/hello but it returns object not found. Otherwise I appreciate.